# Applied R Function in Cpp with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, function, rcpp

My Question is pretty straightforward:

I'm currently trying to speed up my r code by using Rcpp to write some c++ code. But now I need to insert some functions I wrote in R by myself. How could I do that?

Edit1: Sample Code.

I have three function I wrote myself, they are called:

1.pre_process.
2.transfer_element.
3.prediction.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

NumericVector sel_p;
NumericVector pur_p;
int k = sel_p.length();
int bps = 20;
NumericVector pur_p_temp( pur_p.begin(), sel_p.end());
float profit = sum(sel_p) + sum(pur_p_temp);
NumericVector minute_data;
NumericMatrix dataset;

int main(){
  while(TRUE){
    //GET MINUTE DATA HERE.
    if (minute_data == dataset.end()) {
      std::cout << "repeating" << std::endl;
    } else if(minute_data != dataset.end()) {
      dataset.push_back(minute_data)
      std::cout << "Working!No Worries." << std::endl;
      if (dataset.nrow() > bps) {
        //transfer_element here.
        //pre_process here.
        //prediction here.
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In R code, I will use "dget" function to invoke stored function and I have no idea about doing that in c++ or Rcpp.

All three function are wrote in pure R code and transfer them into C++ is gonna kill me. If more information is needed please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Peter

Comment: Please share an example of your C++ and R code, and what you're trying to do with them. If it's a lot of code, make up a small example.

Comment: Sure, thanks for advising.

Comment: checkout RInside http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html

Comment: I did checked RInside couple times, but it might be I'm not that into C++, I still have no clue about how to apply functions....but thanks for telling me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*C++* is a different beast than *R*. Add in the need to **transfer** an object from *R* into *C++* and things can get a bit hairy.

---

Consider:

```
NumericVector sel_p;
NumericVector pur_p;
int k = sel_p.length();
int bps = 20;
NumericVector pur_p_temp( pur_p.begin(), sel_p.end());
float profit = sum(sel_p) + sum(pur_p_temp);
NumericVector minute_data;
NumericMatrix dataset;
```

There is no scope outside of the *global* scope that these variables can rest in. However, the lack of proper initialization is problematic. In particular, consider the `pur_p` variable that is initially defined, but not initialized. This variable then gets operated later on to create `pur_p_temp`.

---

Next, let's briefly talk about `int main()` use. In this particular case, functions must *not* be named in this manner as that is *R*'s prerogative. So, let's call your function `void hey_ya()`.

In addition, to use your function within *R*, you need to specify `// [[Rcpp::export]]`

---

With the above being said, you should structure your code like so:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void hey_ya(Rcpp::NumericVector sel_p, Rcpp::NumericVector pur_p,
            Rcpp::NumericVector minute_data, Rcpp::NumericMatrix dataset){

    int k = sel_p.length();
    int bps = 20;
    Rcpp::NumericVector pur_p_temp( pur_p.begin(), sel_p.end());
    float profit = sum(sel_p) + sum(pur_p_temp);

    while(TRUE){
        // GET MINUTE DATA HERE.
        if (minute_data == dataset.end()) {
            Rcpp::Rcout << "repeating" << std::endl;
        } else if(minute_data != dataset.end()) {
            dataset.push_back(minute_data)
            Rcpp::Rcout << "Working! No Worries." << std::endl;
            if (dataset.nrow() > bps) {
                //transfer_element here.
                //pre_process here.
                //prediction here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

However, since you notably left out a complete example... Here's a toy display of how to work with `dget` in Rcpp.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector dget_example(std::string file) {
    // Obtain environment containing function
    Rcpp::Environment base("package:base");

    // Make function callable from C++
    Rcpp::Function dget_r = base["dget"];

    // Call the function and receive its list output
    Rcpp::NumericVector res = dget_r(Rcpp::Named("file") = file);
    // Change the above data type depending on _X_ object.

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your patient and complete reply first, I really appreciate it. I'm still a beginner in C++, so please forgive me if i asked some really stupid question. So how should I changing my data type accordingly? Like, is it depending on my output or input?

Comment: Dependent on what is in `file` being read with `dget`. In this case, I assumed that it is of type `Numeric`.

Comment: I am trying to read a R file called trans.R, is how you judge the type? it is fully written in R code, I will try numeric.

Comment: I did a tiny change in switching numbericvector to function, I didn't explain my purpose clearly. But your code is really helpful, thanks a lot.

Comment: For sure, it says the upvote won't show up until there is 15 or more or something, but did you receive me vote?

Comment: @PetaGlz Yup! Cheers mate. Have fun in the _Rcpp_ verse!